# How to submit AJAX Form using radio button change event?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a AJAX form & I want to submit it on radio button change event.

AJAX Form:

```
     @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Vote", "Rate", null ,
                       new AjaxOptions
                           {
                               InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                               HttpMethod = "GET",
                               OnFailure = "searchFailed",
                               LoadingElementId = "ajax-loader",
                               UpdateTargetId = "searchresults",
                           },new { id = "voteForm" }))
                {
                <input type="radio" name="Stars" value="1">
                <input type="radio" name="Stars" value="2">
                <input type="radio" name="Stars" value="3">

                }
```

I uses following code but it does not work.

```
       $("#voteForm").ajaxSubmit({ url: '/Vote/Vote', type: 'get' });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("input[name='Stars']").change(function() {
            $("#voteForm").ajaxSubmit({ url: '/Vote/Vote', type: 'get' });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I added this code to my project, but did not work. Where is the wrong? Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

@Babul Mirdha `Ajax.BeginForm` is a mechanism that works fine, but customize specific submit behaviors very different from the standard can generate big headache. I think now you know that.

Every time I (and many other developers will say it too) need to develop some custom behavior I use the basic Jquery. Like this:

In your controller:

```
public JsonResult Vote(YourModel model)
{
    // do something:
    // model.Stars

    return Json(new { message = "Success" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Your model:

```
public class YourModel
{
    // ...
    public int Stars { get; set; }
}
```

And your view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#voteForm input[name=Stars]").change(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/Vote',
                type: 'GET',
                data: $("form#voteForm").serialize(),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data.message);
                },
                error: function (jq, message) {
                    alert(message);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<form id="voteForm" action="@Url.Action("Vote")">
    <input type="radio" name="Stars" value="1" checked="checked"/>
    <input type="radio" name="Stars" value="2" />
    <input type="radio" name="Stars" value="3" />
    <input type="text" name="Tbx" />
</form>
```

This way you have full control over behavior.