# Radio Button Toggle call C# Function

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-core

i build this application:

[CRUD Application with ASP.NET Core 3.0 & Entity Framework 3.0 Using Visual Studio 2019](https://www.syncfusion.com/blogs/post/build-crud-application-with-asp-net-core-entity-framework-visual-studio-2019.aspx)

Now i found a nice toggle(https://codepen.io/shaneheyns/pen/OPWGry):

i will only have the toggle like this code:

```
<div class="pricing-switcher">
            <p class="fieldset">
                <input type="radio" name="duration-1" value="monthly" id="monthly-1" checked>
                <label for="monthly-1">Monthly</label>
                <input type="radio" name="duration-1" value="yearly" id="yearly-1">
                <label for="yearly-1">Yearly</label>
                <span class="switch"></span>
            </p>
        </div>
```

everything works(i copied the .css style), **but how can i execute a C# function if monthly is checked**?

i searched a lot and tried alot but nothing worked.
the only things is a extra submit button.
but i will something like an Onchange event or something that called a C# Function in my Controller.

if i have a button i would code it like this:

```
 <a asp-action="monthly">Test!!</a>
```

Can somebody please help me?

Thank you!

**now i updated my Code like this:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("test1", "Test"))
{

<div class="pricing-switcher">
    <p class="fieldset">
        <input type="radio" name="Isactive" value="test1" id="monthly-1"checked>
        <label for="monthly-1">monthly</label>
        <input type="radio" name="test1" value="test2" id="yearly-1">
        <label for="yearly-1">yearly</label>
        <span class="switch"></span>
    </p>
</div>
```

and the .js Code:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

    $("input[name='Isactive']").change(function () {
        $(this).closest("form").submit();
    });

});
```

now the function in Controller is like this:

```
   public void Isactive()
    {
      Debug.WriteLine("test");
    }
```

The Function was called thanks! But 2 problems:

1. **The switch does not toggle**
2. **On click the site will redirect to IsActive the browserlink is**  https://localhost:44311/Test/Isactive

How to fix these?
Sorry i know C#, but html/js/css are new to me

Comment: You need to use jQuery to trigger event for events on radio button. And in the event handler you need to call web API using Ajax to get the c# code executed.

Comment: Hi, okay thanks. Do you have an example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17652291/how-to-submit-ajax-form-using-radio-button-change-event

Comment: updated the Code, but need help. please

Answer (score 0):

> The switch does not toggle

For the first question, You should keep the name of two radio button the same.

```
<div class="pricing-switcher">
<p class="fieldset">
    <input type="radio" name="duration-1" value="test1" id="monthly-1"checked>
    <label for="monthly-1">monthly</label>
    <input type="radio" name="duration-1" value="test2" id="yearly-1">
    <label for="yearly-1">yearly</label>
    <span class="switch"></span>
</p>
</div>
```

> On click the site will redirect to IsActive the browserlink is https://localhost:44311/Test/Isactive

For the second question, This is the default behavior for form submission, the form points to this url. If you want to stay at the current page, you can submit the form with ajax.

Comment: Ah thank you for the information. Now i know where to search!